# Quarkus extensions nediness

Tags: java, quarkus

What are quarkus extensions meant for?

There are a bunch of extensions I'm asking myself if they are redundant or superfluous.

For example, why quarkus is providing an "Hibernate ORM" extension? Why ain't able to just use Hibernate straightforwardly?

Answer (score 9):

It's using Hibernate ORM under the hood.

Extensions are there for several reasons:

- they tie the library to the Quarkus development model. Typically the Hibernate ORM extension will use the configuration properties coming from the `application.properties` and bootstrap the persistence unit;
- they allow to move things from runtime to build time: in the case of ORM, when using GraalVM, all the Hibernate metadata are built when compiling the native image;
- it allows configuring things for GraalVM native images, typically registering class for reflection, adding resources...
- also in the case of Hibernate ORM, some of our defaults are not the same as the historical Hibernate ORM defaults.